# How do I import a Python file within another script which is in another file directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game, and I want the program to run the introduction when I select start game. So I want the start game Python file to run the other Python scripts that runs the introduction of my game.

This is for a game I am making for a school project.

```py
sys.path.insert(1, '/Macintosh HD/Users/aryanafzali/PycharmProjects/The Shattering Stone/Code/Code/Introduction')

import Introdction
```

I want the Python file in the **Introdcution file** to run when I select start game (in the original start game Python file).

Comment: You have two different versions of *[introduction](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/introduction#Noun)*, both misspelled:  *Introdction* and *Introdcution*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add `sys.path.insert(1, '/Macintosh HD/Users/aryanafzali/PycharmProjects/The Shattering Stone/Code/Code')` (not the `Introduction` directory). However it's an "It depends." type of situation, you did not provide enough information.

EDIT for clarity. This is what you should keep in mind: If you have `"/dir/to/some/file.py"` than you could add `"/dir/to/some"` to `sys.path` and `import file` after that, and you could use functions and symbols from `file.py` as `file.some_function` or `file.SomeClass`.

Comment: The code comes back with the error. No module named Introdcution. And the folder the python file is stored in is called Introduction (stupid of me) but thats the full directory

Comment: As I said, the main problem (with your question) is that you don't provide enough information. You should consider this when asking a question https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
Provide the sample code and directory listing of the directory you are trying to include. If you understand and follow the instructions, then it should work.